# linq vs t SQL syntax

Tags: sql, linq, syntax

I'm newbie with linq and I used to develop with T-SQL.
I've a 'simple' query in T-SQL like this :

```
select article.Id, article.code,article.designation1,sum(inventaire.quantite),
sum(inventaire.quantite) * article.PrixStockArticle,
sum(inventaire.quantite) * article.PrixVenteArticle 
from inventaire 
inner join article on article.Id = inventaire.articleId 
left outer join articleFamille on articleFamille.Id = article.cleClientArticleFamille 
left outer join articleFamille2 on articleFamille2.Id = article.cleClientArticleFamille2 
group by article.Id,article.code, article.designation1,article.PrixVenteArticle,article.PrixStockArticle
```

I want to make this query with linq and entity framework.
The simple way to make multiple left outer join, group by and sum is :

```
var result = (from f in _context.Inventaire.Include(i => i.oArticle)
join oArticle in _context.Article on f.articleId equals oArticle.Id
join oArticleFamille in _context.ArticleFamille on oArticle.cleClientArticleFamille equals oArticleFamille.Id
into InventaireList
from subpet in InventaireList.DefaultIfEmpty()
join oArticleFamille2 in _context.ArticleFamille2 on oArticle.cleClientArticleFamille2 equals oArticleFamille2.Id
into InventaireList2
from subpet2 in InventaireList2.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (f.clientId == oUser.clientId)
let essai = new
{
oArticle = f.oArticle
,
codeFamille = subpet == null ? "" : subpet.code
,
codeFamille2 = subpet2 == null ? "" : subpet2.code                         

}
orderby essai.oArticle.code
group f by essai into fGroup
select new InventaireViewModel
{
oArticle = fGroup.Key.oArticle
,
quantite = fGroup.Sum(f => f.quantite)
,
valStock = fGroup.Sum(f => f.quantite) * fGroup.Key.oArticle.PrixStockArticle
                       ,
valVente = fGroup.Sum(f => f.quantite) * fGroup.Key.oArticle.PrixVenteArticle
}).ToList();
```

Is there an easier way to make this linq query?
Two solutions, I'm too bad with linq or linq is good for inner join and very very simple query but not for a real application (if I've to make 31 lines of code instead of 4 lines in T-SQL, why MS advise to use linq?????
And why MS not implement the left outer join? They never use left outer?

Thanks for reply !
Nice dev!

Comment: Actually the LINQ query would be much smaller and easier to write if you put proper [navigation properties](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) in your entity model (classes) - one of the beautiful things in EF. So, can we see your classes?

Comment: You're right! Navigations property make linq very simple! Thank you!